# Android WifiConfiguration

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm trying to connect to a specific BSSID, which is turning out to be problematic. I get the BSSID I want to connect to in a `ScanResult`. Then I pass that in to a function that will set up a `WifiConfiguration` using the BSSID and connect to it. However, the device doesn't actually connect to this network.

To see what was going on, I printed out all the configured networks by looping through the `WifiManager`'s `getConfiguredNetworks()` function and I'm seeing that almost all the configured networks have `null` as the BSSID, even the one I configured manually. There's also one network that has `any` as its BSSID entry.

What, exactly, does the BSSID field in `WifiConfiguration` mean? The documentation states:

> public String BSSID
>
> When set, this network configuration entry should only be used when associating with the AP having the specified BSSID. The value is a string in the format of an Ethernet MAC address, e.g., XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX where each X is a hex digit.

`any` and `null` are certainly not in that format. Here's the code I'm using to print out:

```
for (WifiConfiguration config : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
    Log.d("TEST", config.BSSID + " " + config.status + " " + config.priority + " " + config.SSID);
}
```

Edit: I added `toString()` to my print statement when I make the WifiConfiguration. Calling `configuration.BSSID` returns `null` while `toString` gives me a BSSID. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that for some reason Android freaks out if you set a BSSID and no SSID. Setting the SSID as well results in the BSSID showing up as it should.

Comment: In my case I am setting both, SSID as well as BSSID. However the configuration saved only has the SSID and BSSID is null.